# jQuery DataTables - AJAX call working but Data is not being graphed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to get the results of my AJAX request (JSON structure) to be created within a table using the Data Tables jQuery library.  The AJAX call is being executed successfully, but for some reason the table is not being created.

HTML:

```
div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" data-page-length='14'>
    </table>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://API END POINT",
        dataSrc: "_deployments",
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        }          
 },
 columns: [
        { data: "service_name" },
        { data: "git_organization" }
    ]
  });
});
```

JSON structure (where each object within the `"_deployments"` array is a series of key value pairs that I will need to access, BUT not ALL of them will be used:

```
{
"_total": 1853,
"_page_size": 10,
"_page_current": 1,
"_page_last": 186,
"_deployments": [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {}]
  }
```

From what I've read from the docs, I'm specifying that the required data is an array of objects by declaring the value of the `dataSrc` to be `"_deployments"`. I have also tried to specify the name/value pair to be `{ data: "key" },...` but that was not working either.  At this point, a bit confused to what the actual problem is.

I previously have tried having the columns pre-defined in the HTML table, as well as a `thead` and `tbody`, but I read that wasn't necessarily required and it didn't solve the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### SOLUTION

jQuery DataTables needs one of the following in order to initialize the table.

1. Proper HTML markup for `table` element with `thead`, `tbody` and optionally `tfoot` elements. See [official documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/installation#HTML) for more details.

   For example:

   ```html
   <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" data-page-length='14'>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Service Name</th>
            <th>Organization</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
   </table>
   ```
2. Alternatively you can use empty `table` element but need to specify title with [`columns.title`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.title) and optionally data source with [`columns.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) for each column.

   For example:

   ```js
   columns: [
       { title: "Service Name", data: "service_name" },
       { title: "Organization", data: "git_organization" }
   ]
   ```

   See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/wy98pyog/) for code and demonstration.

#### NOTES

It looks like your server-side script returns paginated data, however format differs from what [jQuery DataTables would expect](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). In addition to the changes above you would either need to change format of your data or use [`columns.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.dataSrc) option to convert your data format into what jQuery DataTables understands.

Comment: I gave both methods a shot and the table that is being created just hangs on "loading data" with no data being put into it.  If you look at the JS code above, you can see I'm using ```dataSrc: "_deployments"``` -- is this not enough? I thought it would be as it is an array of objects, which from what I can tell is an option DataTables expects?

Comment: @Lukon, Also remove `success` handler, it should not be used with jQuery Datatables.

Comment: Odd.  Removing that success handler worked.. I think. Would you mind explaining why?

Comment: See documentation for [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax#object) option - `success` - *Must not be overridden as it is used internally in DataTables*.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted as answer, appreciate your help.